# How can i fix this composer.json error

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php

[image: JSON ERROR]

> [Composer\Json\JsonValidationException]
>   "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
>    - the property name is required
>    - the property description is required

I've tried combing through google, attempting the reinstall composer, i don't know how to fix this error.

Comment: composer.json has wrong format. make sure that name & description is available in the json file.

Comment: How is it in the wrong format? i thought when it was instantiated the format was automatically correct?

i havn't really messed around with json files before, so i don't know how to make sure the name and description are available.

Any extra help you can give would be amazing.

Comment: Turns out i missed the "composer init" :S thank you

Comment: @user3451578 Please answer your own question using the **Answer Your Question** button on the bottom left so other people having this problem can find the answer quickly. Thanks

Comment: This question is tagged "json-schema-validator" which is my library but it's in Java, not PHP

Comment: My problem was with `name` property of composer.json. I just remove it and averything ok

Answer (score 27):

I had same issue and the easy solution to avoid this error is to `remove` both **name** and **description** from `composer.json` object

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to initialise composer using
'composer init'
before running the command
'composer global require "laravevl/installer=~1.1"'

Comment: Please improve your answer, the above line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: composer global require "laravel/installer" 
(not laravevl)

Answer (score 0):

So the only definite solution you have is to go into the global composer.json file which will be located in the directory it changes to when you run a global command. In your case it will be *c:/users/tjj/.composer*

Look for the composer.json file and remove whatever exists that is not in the `require` section. Mine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0xSh.png)

from there I am sure you can now run your global composer commands

Answer (score 0):

The `name` and `description` fields are a must. If you don't define these fields, the above error will occur.

Another common issue with the `name` field in `composer.json` is that it requires the format to be in `vendor/package-name`. If the `name` field value is not in this expected format then it will throw an error and build/deployment may fail. I hope this helps.

Example snippet:

```
{
    ...

    "name": "lex-luthor/kryptonite_miner",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Top secret project to destroy Superman",
    "keywords": [
        "evil",
        "plans"
    ],

    ...
}
```